# multi-tab/panel control does not always respond correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tabs that open and close panels. Multiple tabs/panels can be open at a time. Followed is my current solution:

```
protected static int[] tabControls = { 0, 0 };

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            storyPanel.Visible = true;
            hoursPanel.Visible = false;
        }
    }

/* ===== TAB CONTROLS ===== */
    protected void Tab1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControls[0] == 1)
        {
            storyPanel.Visible = true;
            Tab1.CssClass = "Clicked";
            tabControls[0] = 0;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#storyPostBack';", true);
        }
        else
        {
            storyPanel.Visible = false;
            Tab1.CssClass = "Initial";
            tabControls[0] = 1;
        }
    }

    protected void Tab2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControls[1] == 1)
        {
            hoursPanel.Visible = true;
            Tab2.CssClass = "Clicked";
            tabControls[1] = 0;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#hoursPostBack';", true);
        }
        else
        {
            hoursPanel.Visible = false;
            Tab2.CssClass = "Initial";
            tabControls[1] = 1;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#storyPostBack';", true);
        }
    }
```

Sometimes the tab needs to be pressed twice for it to respond and open the panel as well as receive the css changes to itself. I cant figure out why. Additionally, is there a better approach.

EDIT:

It's actually not tabs, sorry for not being clear. It's the illusion of tabs using buttons/panels/css:

[image]

Server controls:

```
<table width="80%" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Button Text="Tab 1" BorderStyle="None" ID="Tab1" CssClass="Initial" runat="server"
          OnClick="Tab1_Click" />
      <asp:Button Text="Tab 2" BorderStyle="None" ID="Tab2" CssClass="Initial" runat="server"
          OnClick="Tab2_Click" />
         <asp:Panel ID="storyPanel" runat="server">
          <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 1px; border-color: #666; border-style: solid">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h3>
                  <span>tab content here </span>
                </h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="hoursPanel" runat="server">
          <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 1px; border-color: #666; border-style: solid">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h3>
                  tab 2 content here
                </h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </asp:Panel>
</table>
```

Comment: What tabControl are u using? Pls provide some relevant parts of your markup code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the initial state of all tabs is visible:

```
protected static int[] tabControls = { 0, 0 };
```

But in fact, only one tab would actually be visible right?  Or are all the panels supposed to be visible at the same time?  If your tabControls variable is out of sync with the actual visibility of the panels, it may require clicking twice.  Once to change the tabControls to invisible, and then one to change it back to visible again.  To fix, just do:

```
protected static int[] tabControls = { 0, 1 };
```